# .Net Core project does not find the SDK or so it seems

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am using instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code to try and build my first Azure Functions project in .Net Core

My problem is I cannot build it:

```
PS C:\work\proj> dotnet build .\proj.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. [C:\work\proj\proj.csproj]

Build FAILED.

c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. [C:\work\proj\proj.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.56
PS C:\work\proj>
```

Here is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.28" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have installed the latest .Net Core SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.700-windows-x64-installer, so:

```
PS C:\> dir 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\'


    Directory: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----          6/7/2018  6:35 PM                1.0.0-preview2-003131
da----         2/21/2018  7:57 PM                2.1.4
d-----         10/2/2018  9:04 PM                2.1.403
d-----         12/3/2018  9:46 AM                2.1.500
d-----          1/3/2019  9:06 PM                2.1.502
d-----         5/23/2019  8:18 PM                2.1.507
d-----         6/30/2019 11:27 PM                2.1.700
d-----         6/30/2019 11:27 PM                NuGetFallbackFolder

PS C:\>
```

I do not understand why the build selects version 2.1.4. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I am pretty sure it is related. For some reason I have environment variable 
`MSBuildSdksPath`:

```
PS C:\> $env:MSBuildSdksPath
c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks
PS C:\>
```

Installing the latest SDK did not update it. Why?

Build succeeds when I remove it in the local console. Is it safe to remove it from the environment variables at all?

**EDIT 2**

```
PS C:\> dotnet --list-sdks
1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.502 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.507 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
PS C:\>
```

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --list-sdks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deleted the environment variable `MSBuildSdksPath`.

Still do not know what added it, why and whether I am out of the woods by just removing it. Will gladly accept a more information answer.

Comment: Spent a day trying to figure out why my machine kept trying to use a 2.2 sdk version. Turned out this was why

Answer (score 1):

Try to install x32 and x64. First I had installed only x64 and this was the wrong one... was my mistake but maybe you did the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

I had this problem too, If you are using visual studio 2017 then this version of the .Net Core SDK will not work, you will need to use this one

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.507-windows-x64-installer

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after cleaning up previous sdks before 3.0.0.
I had installed an x86 version before.
I didn't want to installed both X86 and X64 versions again.
I looked at my envirnment variables and and saw an entry in the PATH pointing to the dotnet folder.  I changed it to be C:\Program Files\dotnet\   and now I'm okay.